# How can Fix Broken Pipe Error when use Data Driver in Robot Framework?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, robotframework

when I use Data Driver in Eclipse with Red Plugin, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/mh/fdm2ck3d2_7_qkj7dsfgvbyc0000gn/T/RobotTempDir1374037174968069811/TestRunnerAgent.py", line 700, in _send_to_server_json
    self.decoder_encoder._write('{"%s": %s}' % (name, json_encoded_obj))
  File "/var/folders/mh/fdm2ck3d2_7_qkj7dsfgvbyc0000gn/T/RobotTempDir1374037174968069811/TestRunnerAgent.py", line 756, in _write
    self._file_to_write.flush()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 607, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[ ERROR ] Calling method 'start_keyword' of listener '/var/folders/mh/fdm2ck3d2_7_qkj7dsfgvbyc0000gn/T/RobotTempDir1374037174968069811/TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[ ERROR ] Calling method 'start_keyword' of listener '/var/folders/mh/fdm2ck3d2_7_qkj7dsfgvbyc0000gn/T/RobotTempDir1374037174968069811/TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Here is my code

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           DataDriver    ${CURDIR}/data/login_data.xlsx    DataDriven
Resource          ${CURDIR}/resources/login_resources.robot

Suite Setup       Open Browser To Login Page
Test Teardown     Close Browser
Test Setup        Open Browser To Login Page
#Test Template     Invalid Login

*** Test Cases ***
Login With Invalid Data ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD}    a    b
    [Template]    Invalid Login
    [Tags]        Invalid

Login With Valid Data ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD}    a     b
    [Tags]        Valid
    [Template]    Valid Login

*** Keywords ***
Invalid Login
    [Arguments]    ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    [Tags]    Flat
    Input Username    ${USERNAME}
    Input Pass    ${PASSWORD}
    Click Submit Button
    Create HalfTrip Menu Should Not Be Open
```

I tried run this code in Pycharm, this bugs does not appeared. This bug just appear in Eclipse. I think it is caused by the Settings